# How to type italics or bold inside code in a comment

Tags: support, comments, markdown, code-formatting

How can you put italics or bold **inside code in a comment**?

For example, to produce `normal italic` in a comment I've tried

- `` `normal _italic_` ``
- `` `normal `_`italic`_ ``
- `<code>normal _italic_</code>`
- `<code>normal <i>italic</i></code>`

But none of these work. I've also tried replacing the underscores with asterisks:

- `` `normal *italic*` ``
- `` `normal `*`italic`* ``
- `<code>normal *italic*</code>`
- `<code>normal <i>italic</i></code>`

Note that the last three items in each list work as expected when applied outside of comments (i.e. in questions and answers). I've also read through the [comment formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) section of the site, but I still can't figure it out. And I know this type of thing is possible because I've seen it in the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment1060740_3122).

Answer (score 11):

You're almost there, you just have to reverse the order of the formatting:

- `` **`bold`** `` produces **`bold`**
- `` *`italic`* `` produces *`italic`*

As you can see, this works in posts as well.

Comment: That is definitely helpful. But is there a way to make a combined piece of code with both normal text and italics, as in the example I mentioned in my question? It seems that if you try to put `*\`italic\`*` next to `\`normal\``, the formatting breaks.

Comment: `normal` *`italic`* works (with a space in between). Zero-width Unicode spaces seem to be stripped, so that doesn't help.

Comment: Could you not use <I> italic </I>

Comment: That works too (in posts, not in comments), but is longer to type.

Answer (score 1):

To use both normal and formatted text in a comment, make sure that a space exists to either side of the formatted text, as shown below:

*`Markdown:`*

```
*`This`* comment uses normal and ***`formatted`*** text.
```

*`Output:`*

*`This`* comment uses normal and ***`formatted`*** text.

To use *`italic`*, **`bold`**, and ***`bold italic`*** in comments, see the raw Markdown for each below.

*`Markdown:`*

```
*`This sentence is in italic`*
```

*`Output:`*

*`This sentence is italic`*

*`Markdown:`*

```
**`This sentence is bold.`**
```

*`Output:`*

**`This sentence is bold.`**

*`Markdown:`*

```
***`This sentence is bold and italic`***
```

*`Output:`*

***`This sentence is bold and italic`***

This [answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/908/288974)  is also worth reviewing as it explains formatting text in comments in more detail.

Comment: The isn't what the author was asking for, and is already covered in the existing answer. They wanted to know if it was possible to use both bold and unformatted (or other formatted) text within one piece of inline code, without having to break it up.

Comment: @animuson The question doesn't specifically ask for one piece of inline code; please elaborate as to how you made that inference. The posted question has no accepted answer; from that most would infer the need to add an answer. ***`⁶⁴/³`***

Comment: All of their examples in the question emphasize that desire, and they also further clarified that in a comment under the other answer. A question not having an accepted answer also does not mean it is unanswered or needs another one. As said before, you explain how to do the same thing already explained in the other answer - you've just done so in a longer format.

Comment: Your feedback is appreciated, though we differ in perspective. The biggest advantage of Stack Exchange *`et al.`* is being able to solve a problem or learn new concepts faster due to having the problem explained from multiple perspectives at once in the form of attempted answers. The accepted answer isn't always adequate; some of us fools in the rough need another explanation. ***`⁶⁴/³`***

Comment: The answer does not add anything new, as @animuson already said, however it can stay as it does give more details than the existing answer. Kind of "more of the same". :)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard May the Source serve you well.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda How is it possible to acknowledge that my answer gives more details than the existing answer while simultaneously stating that it does not add anything new?